# Bash script - remove lines by looking ahead

Tags: bash, unix

I have a csv file where some rows have an empty first field, and some rows have content in the first field. The rows with content in the first field are header rows.

I would like to remove every unnecessary header row. The best way I can see of doing this is by deleting every row for which:

1. First field is not empty
2. First field in the following row is not empty

I do not necessarily need to keep the data in the same file, so I can see this being possible using grep, awk, or sed, but none of my attempts have come close to working.

Example input:

```
header1,value1,etc
,value2,etc
header2,value3,etc
header3,value4,etc
,value5,etc
```

Desired output:

```
header1,value1,etc
,value2,etc
header3,value4,etc
,value5,etc
```

Since the `header2` line is not followed by a line with an empty field 1, it is an unnecessary header row.

Comment: could you tell more about what a typical row looks like? Also can you what do you mean by "unnecessary header row"?

Answer (score 4):

```
awk -F, '$1{h=$0;next}h{print h;h=""}1' file
```

`-F,`: Use comma as a field separator

`$1{h=$0;next}`: If the first field has data ( other than 0 ), save the line and go on to the next line.

`h{print h;h=""}1`: If there is a saved header line, print it and forget it. (This can only execute if there is nothing in $1 because of the `next` above.)

`1`: print the current line.

Answer (score 0):

These kind of tasks are often conceptually easier by reversing the file and checking if the *previous* line is a header:

```
tac file |
  awk -F, '$1 && have_header {next} {print; have_header = length($1)}' |
  tac
```